# Calculate propeller efficiency

Tags: propeller

I have a test bench that can test the thrust of a propeller with my electric motor, is there a way that I can calculate the propeller efficiency (η<sub>p</sub>)?

Comment: Hi, hello there. There are [some questions on the topic here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22propeller%20efficiency%22%20is%3aq%20closed%3a0), be sure to check them out, and preferably edit your question with anything specific that you still wish to know if those didn't work out for you

Comment: Only if you can simultaneously measure how much power the motor draws, and you don't mind correcting for the many other factors mentioned elsewhere on this site.  If you're measuring static thrust (zero airspeed) and don't have a wind tunnel, there are ways to estimate in-flight efficiency at various airspeeds, too.